# Invoking Fragment from a popup android

Tags: android, popup, preference

In my main activity layout,I have an image button.

On clicking it,a popup pops up.The layout of the popup is as follows.

test.xml

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:background="@android:color/black">

                <Button 
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/b_help"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Help"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
                <Button 
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/b_pref"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Preferences"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
                <Button 
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/b_about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"/>   

            </LinearLayout>
```

The popup is displayed by the following code from MainActivity.java

```
        btnOpenPopup = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
            btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getBaseContext());
             popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

        }});
```

The popup window class is as follows
PopupWindow.java

```
            public class PopupWindow extends android.widget.PopupWindow implements View.OnClickListener{
            Context ctx;
            View popupView;
            Button help,pref,about;

            public PopupWindow(Context context)
            {
                super(context);



                ctx = context;
                popupView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test, null);
                setContentView(popupView);

                setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                // Closes the popup window when touch outside of it - when looses focus
                setOutsideTouchable(true);
                setFocusable(true);

                // Removes default black background
                setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

                pref = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.b_pref);     
                pref.setOnClickListener(this);




            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.b_pref:break;

                case R.id.b_help:break;
                case R.id.b_about:break;
                }

            }


        }
```

Now on clicking the preferences button in the popup,i need to display the preference fragment.

I tried this ,for setOnClickListener for the preference button,but it is not working as the popupwindow class cannot extend fragmentactivity and getFragmentManager() is not happening.

```
            FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                                .beginTransaction();
        Prefs mPrefsFragment = new Prefs();
        //this line..
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prefs);
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

How can i invoke the preffragment using the button from popup??
Any help will be much appreciated.Cause I am badly stuck at this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you save a reference to the fragment manager you got as a variable in another situation, such as when you first started, and use that instead. Takes a little memory, but the context you are in will not effect how you get your manager then.